# $httpBackend.expect vs. $httpBackend.when

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After reading the AngularJS document fo $httpBackend, I am still not very clear what the difference between `$httpBackend.expect` and `$httpBackend.when` as both are functions for mocking http requests.

Could someone help explain the difference between these two functions? And also when shall I use `$httpBackend.when` instead of `$httpBackend.expect`?

Comment: Google: `$httpBackend.expect vs. $httpBackend.when` -> [I feel lucky] -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945758/what-is-the-difference-between-expect-and-when-in-httpbackend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is fairly clear [in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend), however, here is the main difference:

`$httpBackend.when` will return you a fake http response, but **not fail the test** if the URL declared is never called.

`$httpBackend.expect` will return you a fake http response. but **fail the test** if the URL declared is never called.

So, `expect` sets up an test expectation that the test **must** call the URL that is set up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Simple and easy to understand.