# There are `n` number of calls to an http api in angularjs. Should I expect them `n` number of times?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

One of my angularjs files had a code construct similar to the below:

```
this.examplecall = function() {
         var a = apiconfig.getconfig();
         ....
         //some lines of code
         ....
         var b = apiconfig.getconfig();
}
```

And I started to write unit tests for it through angular spec - Jasmine, ended up with the below stub of code.

```
    describe("test examplecall")...

    it("should test cofig call in examplecall", function() {

     $httpBackend.expectGET(GET_CONFIG).respond(200);

    });
```

The above code throws exception telling **"unexpected GET.."**

When I added an extra `expectGET`, things worked out fine. See below:

```
describe("test examplecall")...

    it("should test cofig call in examplecall", function() {

     $httpBackend.expectGET(GET_CONFIG).respond(200);
     $httpBackend.expectGET(GET_CONFIG).respond(200);

    });
```

From this, I infer that if there are **two** api calls in a particular function, then I have to expect it **two** times.

1. Does that mean, if there are `n` **same** api calls in a particular code stub, I have to expect them `n` number of times ?
2. Are there any similar constructs like,

   **$httpBackend.WheneverexpectGET(GET_CONFIG).respond(200**);

so, whenever we call a API just return `200` status like above?

Thank you for your comments on this...

**EDIT:** (read the accepted answer before going through this.)

Thanks to @kamituel for the wonderful answer.

To summarise with the information provided in his answer:

1. Use of `expect` :

   1. Expects the order of the API call. It expects that the code should call the api's in the exact order that you expect.
   2. If there are 3 api calls, then you should expect them 3 times.
2. Use of `when` : ($httpBackend.when)

   1. Does not expect if an API call is made or not. Just doesn't throw any error.
   2. `$httpBackend.when` behaves like a mini mock database. Whenever your code, expects some response from an API, supply it. Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `.expectGET` is used to assert that a given request has been made by the application. So you need to call it `n` times if you expect the application to make `n` requests.

If you don't need to assert on that, but only want to make application logic work through any requests it makes, you might want to use `.whenGET` instead. Difference between `.expectXXX` and `.whenXXX` has been already described [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27945901/782609).

**Edit:** not sure which Angular version are you using, but you will find this [in the implementation of `.expectGET`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/eacf06f5cfa69989b5277dd77007c79c96721160/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L1413):

```
expectations.shift();
```

This is invoked once a request is made and matches what was expected. Which means the same expectation is only asserted on once.

It's usually also a good idea to call `.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()` after your test is done, to ensure that each request you specified as epxected using `.expectXXX()` has indeed been made by the application.